# Laravel - load post with custom id via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-routing

I want to load my post via AJAX when I click on a post link, how I can send my post ID via AJAX?

I've got a link in my Blade file:

```
{{ link_to_route($post->type, $post->comments->count() . '&nbsp;' . t('comments'), array('id' => $post->id, 'slug' => $post->slug), array('class' => 'link--to--post')) }}
```

I've got the following route definition:

```
Route::get('news/{id}-{slug?}', ['as' => 'news', 'uses' => 'NewsController@show']);
```

And controller action:

```
public function show($id, $slug = null)
{
    $post = $this->news->getById($id, 'news');

    if ($slug != $post->slug){
     return Redirect::route('news', ['id' => $post->id, 'slug' => $post->slug]);
    }

    Event::fire('posts.views', $post);

    return View::make('post/post', compact('post'));
}
```

And then I'm trying this:

```
var postTitle = $(".link--to--post");

postTitle.click(function () {   
    $.ajax({
        url: '/news/{id}-{slug}',
        type: 'GET',
        data: $(this),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }      
    });

    return false;
});
```

But this doesn't work for me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have `$(this)` in your .ajax call -- what object is `this` pointing to in this context? If `data` is set to an object, the object's attributes will be converted to a query string like `?id=4&slug=foo`, which is probably not what you want here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your javascript should pass the parameters like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/news/' + id + '-' + slug,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }      
});
```

You had `url: '/news/{id}-{slug}'`, which would perform a GET request to `/news/{id}-{slug}`, which isn't a valid route -- you want a URL like `/news/1-foo`.

Comment: i'm trying to add custom attr with `id` and `slug` of the post, and this worked, but i think this is not good variant, no?

Comment: i mean that i add to attributes to my link in blade: data-id="id here" and data-slug="slug here", and then i'm get id and slug via ajax, and this works fine, but i think this is not good solution, or i'm wrong?

Comment: I use attributes like `data-id` all the time -- I don't think it's a bad practice at all.

Comment: If you're asking about your general strategy here, that's not really stack overflow material -- but I can help you solve specific problems if you post specific questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85494/discussion-between-stefan-and-ben).